# how to convert spark sql query result to dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to get spark.sql query result to dataframe ,  when i run below code line it's giving `object` is there any way to read spark.sql give dataframe results

i tried below code but it's give object

```
df = spark_session.sql()  it's give object
```

Comment: SparkSession.sql returns a DataFrame , not sure what object you are trying to imply here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html?highlight=sparksession

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned below steps which make you clarity about how we get the data from rdms using spark SQL and store into dataframe.This expample is best practice to write the spark code for the production scripts.

```
'''
DataFrame creation scripts
@author: Mr. Ravi Kumar

'''
def get_session():
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('basic1').getOrCreate()
    sc=spark.sparkContext
    return sc, spark

#mysql connection details

driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"
user = "root"
pwd = "India@123"

#Building connection and reading data from mysql
def read_data(spark, sc):
    sourceDf = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", driver)\
    .option("url", url)\
    .option("dbtable", "employee")\
    .option("user", user)\
    .option("password", pwd)\
    .load()
    print("Bulid mysql connection successfully ! ")
    return sourceDf
#validating the data
def data_disp(spark,sc):
    df=read_data(spark, sc)
    print("***************************Data Preview*******************************************")
    df.show(truncate=0)
   

#2nd highest employee Job wise
def secondHighest(spark,sc):
    import pyspark.sql.window as W
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    import pyspark.sql.types as T

    sourceDf=read_data(spark,sc)
    #windownspec
    v=W.Window.partitionBy(sourceDf["empid"]).orderBy(sourceDf["salary"].desc())
    highest=sourceDf.withColumn("2nd_Highest", F.dense_rank().over(v))
    return highest
#writing back after processing 
def write_mysql(spark, sc):
    output=secondHighest(spark, sc)
    output.write.format("jdbc").option("driver", driver)\
    .option("url", url)\
    .option("dbtable", "Second_highest")\
    .option("user", user)\
    .option("password", pwd)\
    .save()


    #main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc, spark=get_session()
    read_data(spark,sc)
    data_disp(spark,sc)
    secondHighest(spark,sc)
    write_mysql(spark, sc)
```